# Trigger to prevent deletion of apartment if flat is associated with it

Tags: trigger

### I have to write a trigger to prevent deleting of Apartment records if there are flat records related to it

Here is my solution

.-------------

```
trigger DoNotDeleteAccountHavingRelatedContact on Apartment__c(before delete)  
{  
    for(Apartment__c acc : [SELECT Id FROM Apartment__c WHERE Id IN (SELECT Apartment__c.id FROM Flat__c) AND Id IN :Trigger.oldMap.KeySet()]){
        Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).adderror('Account cannot be deleted');
    }
}
```

Please help..Thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Apartment__c` is the parent object and `Flat__c` is the child object, then instead of:

```
SELECT Apartment__c.id FROM Flat__c
```

you just need:

```
SELECT Apartment__c FROM Flat__c
```

because the `Apartment__c` field holds the `Id`. (`Apartment__r.Id` will also provide the apartment `Id`.)

Comment: There is Master_Detail Relationship between Flat__c and Apartment__c where Flat__c is a Parent and Apartment__c is a Child

Comment: But ur Logic Works....Thank You ...